# Error en servicio NSD de Android 6.0

Tags: java, android

NSD es un servicio que se usa para descubrir otras aplicaciones que ejecutan el mismo servicio en la red local. Estoy intentando hacer funcionar el ejemplo de NSD que ese encuentra en el [sitio oficial de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html).

El problema es que al seleccionar **Search** la aplicación se cae solo en Android 6 (Tengo una tablet con android 4.4.4 y no da el error). Al volver a abrir la app sucede lo mismo. El error es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4741)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10846)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4736)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10846) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22565) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener already in use
    at android.net.nsd.NsdManager.discoverServices(NsdManager.java:559)
    at com.miaplicacion.configurador.NsdHelper.discoverServices(NsdHelper.java:140)
    at com.miaplicacion.configurador.NsdChatActivity.clickDiscover(NsdChatActivity.java:58)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4736) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10846) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22565) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Creo que el error principal es por que "listener already in use". Pero no se como solucionarlo.

Estos son los códigos adicionales:

**activity_main.xml** (el código del botón)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/discover_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="clickDiscover"
    android:text="Buscar" />
```

**NsdChatActivity** (el código de la Activity que recibe el evento click)

```
public void clickDiscover(View v) {
    mNsdHelper.discoverServices();
}
```

**NsdHelper**

```
public void discoverServices() {
    mNsdManager.discoverServices(
            SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
}
```

Comment: Agregas un `OnClickListener` programaticamente?

Comment: No. Lo que hace es agregar un Nsd listener, pero al parecer es como si no se eliminara al salir de la aplicación, entonces al abrir da error por que ya está en uso. Pero no se como repararlo :(

Comment: @ArieCwHat 
Los ejemplos de la documentación están desactualizados y generalmente debes importarlos a Android Studio. En este caso yo tuve el mismo problema, no se debe usar la instancia, debes crear otra (Donde aplique). Agregué la clase completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema real en este ejemplo sobre NSD es:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener already in use

Lo que tienes que asegurar es no usar el mismo listener definido, para esto puedes crear una clase para no usar la misma instancia del listener:

```
//mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener); //Incorrecto.
mNsdManager.resolveService(service, new MyResolveListener());
```

La clase en cuestion sería :

```
private class MyResolveListener implements NsdManager.ResolveListener {
    @Override
    public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*Jorgesys Resolve failed" + errorCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*Jorgesys Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

        if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
            return;
        }
        mService = serviceInfo;
    }
}
```

---

Agrego la clase NsdHelper completa:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.nsdchat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.nsd.NsdServiceInfo;
import android.net.nsd.NsdManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class NsdHelper {

    Context mContext;

    NsdManager mNsdManager;
    NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener;
    NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener;
    NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;

    public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.";

    public static final String TAG = "NsdHelper";
    public String mServiceName = "NsdChat";

    NsdServiceInfo mService;

    public NsdHelper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mNsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    }

    public void initializeNsd() {
        //initializeResolveListener();
        //initializeDiscoveryListener();
        //initializeRegistrationListener();
        //mNsdManager.init(mContext.getMainLooper(), this);
    }

    public void registerService(int port) {
        NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
        serviceInfo.setPort(port);
        serviceInfo.setServiceName(mServiceName);
        serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);
        mRegistrationListener = new MyRegistrationListener(); //Jorgesys
        mNsdManager.registerService(
                serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);

    }

    public void discoverServices() {
        mDiscoveryListener = new MyDiscoveryListener(); //Jorgesys
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(
                SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
    }

    public void stopDiscovery() {
        mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
    }

    public NsdServiceInfo getChosenServiceInfo() {
        return mService;
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener);
    }

    /*** New classes to avoid : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener already in use ***/

    private class MyResolveListener implements NsdManager.ResolveListener {
        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "*Jorgesys Resolve failed" + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "*Jorgesys Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

            if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                return;
            }
            mService = serviceInfo;
        }
    }

    //mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

    private class MyRegistrationListener implements NsdManager.RegistrationListener {

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo NsdServiceInfo) {
            mServiceName = NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo arg0, int arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
        }
    }

    private class MyDiscoveryListener implements NsdManager.DiscoveryListener {
        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service);
            if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
            } else if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
            } else if (service.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName)){
                mNsdManager.resolveService(service, new MyResolveListener());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
            if (mService == service) {
                mService = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html#discoverServices(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.net.nsd.NsdManager.DiscoveryListener)) dice:

> NsdManager.DiscoveryListener: The listener notifies of a successful discovery and is used to stop discovery on this serviceType through a call on stopServiceDiscovery(NsdManager.DiscoveryListener). Cannot be null. **Cannot be in use for an active service discovery.**

El problema parece ser de siglo de vida de tu listener.
Probablemente el `mDiscoveryListener` que pasas ya esta en uso. Trata crear un *Listener* implementando `DiscoveryListener` que instas y guardas en `discoverServices`.

```
public class MiDiscoveryListener implements DiscoveryListener{
    //...
}
```

y crealo en el momento cuando empiezas descubriendo servicios.

```
public void discoverServices() {
    // Solamente tratemos de descubrir servicios si todavía no lo estamos haciendo
    if (null==mDiscoveryListener)
        mDiscoveryListener = new MiDiscoveryListener();
        mNsdManager.discoverServices(SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
    }
}
```

> The application should call stopServiceDiscovery(NsdManager.DiscoveryListener) when discovery of this service type is no longer required, and/or whenever the application is paused or stopped.

```
onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if (null!=mDiscoveryListener){
        mNsdManager.stopDiscovery(mDiscoveryListener);
        mDiscoveryListener=null;
    }
}
```

Probablemente vas a tener que diseñar un poco más exacto los ciclos de vida de tus actividades y cuando se inicia el descubrimiento de servicios.

Comment: Creo que está asi. Cuando digo "el ejemplo de la documentacion oficial" me refiero al que se puede descargar del link,  Este es el còdigo completo https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NsdChat.zip podrías revisarlo si tienes la posibilidad en android 6? Es que en 4.4 exactamente el mismo codigo no me da el error :(

Comment: Si, lo que cambia entre 4.4 y 6 es que no puedes reusar el listener, pero que tienes que trabajar con uno nuevamente instado.